# A simple probabilistic AI for generating random sentences in Java

Tags: java, graph, statistics, data-mining

**Motivation**

I have [this repository](https://github.com/coderodde/SentenceGenerator). It contains a program that analyzes an input text file and builds a word graph: in the graph, each node represents a word in the analyzed text. Now, if there are two consecutive words, `A` and `B`, we create a directed arc from `A` to `B`. When the graph is built, the last step is to draw a probabilistic distribution of children and parents of a node, for each node.

When the graph is complete, in order to generate a sentence, we choose the node corresponding to the single dot (`.`), and go backwards via parent links until the requested number of nodes has been accummulated. When considering at a node what parent to generate, we watch at all the parents \$w_1, \ldots, w_n\$: then the statistical probabilities of each parent becomes \$p_1, \ldots, p_n\$. Finally, we toss a random coin \$c \in [0, \sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_i)\$, and choose the \$w_j\$ such that \$\sum_{i = 1}^j p_i \leq c\$, where \$j\$ is maximized.

In this program, I did not bother to come up with a fancy framework, but instead concentrate on getting the job done; no more, no less.

The book from which the word graph was trained is [War and Peace](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt).

Finally, the typical output might look like this:

```
Producing sentences took 68 ms.
Producing word data took 295 ms.
Building word graph took 300 ms.
Total preprocessing took 663 ms.
> stat belong
--- Outgoing word arcs:
.       , w = 1,0000, p = 0,071429
?       , w = 1,0000, p = 0,071429
entirely, w = 1,0000, p = 0,071429
to      , w = 10,0000, p = 0,714286
you     , w = 1,0000, p = 0,071429
Total of 5 outgoing arcs.
--- Incoming word arcs:
could , w = 1,000, p = 0,071429
i     , w = 2,000, p = 0,142857
may   , w = 1,000, p = 0,071429
might , w = 1,000, p = 0,071429
not   , w = 1,000, p = 0,071429
should, w = 1,000, p = 0,071429
to    , w = 2,000, p = 0,142857
we    , w = 1,000, p = 0,071429
you   , w = 4,000, p = 0,285714
Total of 9 incoming arcs.
> gen 15
>>> The mechanism which hampered his gleaming on pass by unseen hands clenched his imagination .
> gen 15
>>> You she would not our as may turn to remain what had never breathe .
> gen 15
>>> Lighting the married her hand more readily as cruel he was gazing at last .
> gen 15
>>> Secret reasons why the table to the crowds of the transport having limbered up .
```

**Program code**

**`com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator;
 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
 
final class BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution {
 
    public static final class FieldLengths {
        public final int maximumWordLength;
        public final int maximumWeightLength;
        
        private FieldLengths(int maximumWordLength, int maximumWeightLength) {
            this.maximumWordLength = maximumWordLength;
            this.maximumWeightLength = maximumWeightLength;
        }
    }
    
    private static final class Node {
 
        private final DirectedWordGraphNode element;
        private double weight;
        private final boolean isRelayNode;
        private Node leftChild;
        private Node rightChild;
        private Node parent;
        private int numberOfLeafNodes;
 
        Node(DirectedWordGraphNode element, double weight) {
            this.element           = element;
            this.weight            = weight;
            this.numberOfLeafNodes = 1;
            this.isRelayNode       = false;
        }   
 
        Node(double weight) {
            this.element           = null;
            this.weight            = weight;
            this.numberOfLeafNodes = 1;
            this.isRelayNode       = true;
        }
 
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (isRelayNode) {
                return "[" + String.format("%.3f", getWeight()) + " : "
                           + numberOfLeafNodes + "]";
            }
 
            return "(" + String.format("%.3f", getWeight()) + " : "
                       + element + ")";
        }
 
        DirectedWordGraphNode getElement() {
            return element;
        }
 
        double getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }
 
        void setWeight(double weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
 
        int getNumberOfLeaves() {
            return numberOfLeafNodes;
        }
 
        void setNumberOfLeaves(int numberOfLeaves) {
            this.numberOfLeafNodes = numberOfLeaves;
        }
 
        Node getLeftChild() {
            return leftChild;
        }
 
        void setLeftChild(Node block) {
            this.leftChild = block;
        }
 
        Node getRightChild() {
            return rightChild;
        }
 
        void setRightChild(Node block) {
            this.rightChild = block;
        }
 
        Node getParent() {
            return parent;
        }
 
        void setParent(Node block) {
            this.parent = block;
        }
 
        boolean isRelayNode() {
            return isRelayNode;
        }
    }
    
    private final Map<DirectedWordGraphNode, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Node root;
    private double totalWeight;
    private final Random random;
    
    public BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution() {
        this(new Random());
    }
 
    public BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }
 
    public boolean addElement(DirectedWordGraphNode element, double weight) {
        checkWeightNotNaNAndIsPositive(weight);
        Node node = map.get(element);
         
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(element, weight);
            insert(node);
            map.put(element, node);
        } else {
            node.setWeight(node.getWeight() + weight);
            updateMetadata(node, weight, 0);
        }
         
        totalWeight += weight;
        return true;
    }
 
    public boolean contains(DirectedWordGraphNode element) {
        return map.containsKey(element);
    }
 
    public DirectedWordGraphNode sampleElement() {
        checkNotEmpty(map.size());
        double value = totalWeight * random.nextDouble();
        Node node = root;
 
        while (node.isRelayNode()) {
            if (value < node.getLeftChild().getWeight()) {
                node = node.getLeftChild();
            } else {
                value -= node.getLeftChild().getWeight();
                node = node.getRightChild();
            }
        }
 
        return node.getElement();
    }
    
    public double getTotalWeight() {
        return totalWeight;
    }
    
    public double getWeight(DirectedWordGraphNode element) {
        Node node = map.get(element);
        
        if (node == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "The input element not found in the distribution.");
        }
        
        return node.getWeight();
    }
    
    public double getProbability(DirectedWordGraphNode element) {
        Node node = map.get(element);
        
        if (node == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "The input element not found in the distribution.");
        }
        
        return node.getWeight() / totalWeight;
    }
     
    public boolean removeElement(DirectedWordGraphNode element) {
        Node node = map.remove(element);
 
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
 
        delete(node);
        totalWeight -= node.getWeight();
        return true;
    }
 
    public void clear() {
        root = null;
        map.clear();
        totalWeight = 0.0;
    }
      
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }
 
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }
    
    public FieldLengths getFieldLengths() {
        int maximumWordLength = 0;
        int maximumWeightLength = 0;
        
        for (Node node : map.values()) {
            String word = node.getElement().getWord();
            double weight = node.getWeight();
            
            int wordLength = word.length();
            int weightLength = Double.toString(weight).length();
            
            maximumWordLength = Math.max(maximumWordLength, wordLength);
            maximumWeightLength = Math.max(maximumWeightLength, weightLength);
        }
        
        return new FieldLengths(maximumWordLength, 
                                maximumWeightLength);
    }
    
    public String getEntryString(DirectedWordGraphNode element) {
        Node node = map.get(element);
        
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        double probability = node.getWeight() / totalWeight;
        stringBuilder.append(element.toString())
                     .append(", w = ")
                     .append(node.getWeight())
                     .append(", p = ")
                     .append(probability);
        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    
    
     
//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
//        Node node = getMinimumNode();
//        
//        int maximumWordLength = getMaximumWordLength();
//        
//        while (node != null) {
//            String str = 
//                    String.format(
//                            "%+" + (maximumWordLength + 1) + "s", 
//                            node.element.toString());
//            
//            stringBuilder.append(str)
//                         .append(", w = ")
//                         .append(node.getWeight())
//                         .append(", p = ")
//                         .append(node.getWeight() / totalWeight)
//                         .append("\n");
//            
//            node = getSuccessorOf(node);
//        }
//        
//        return stringBuilder.toString();
//    }
    
    private Node getMinimumNode() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        
        Node node = root;
        
        while (node.getLeftChild() != null) {
            node = node.getLeftChild();
        }
        
        return node;
    }
    
    private Node getMinimumNode(Node node) {
        while (node.getLeftChild() != null) {
            node = node.getLeftChild();
        }
        
        return node;
    }
    
    private Node getSuccessorOf(Node node) {
        if (node.getRightChild() != null) {
            return getMinimumNode(node.getRightChild());
        }
        
        Node parent = node.getParent();
        
        while (parent != null && parent.getRightChild() == node) {
            node = parent;
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        
        return parent;
    }
    
    private void bypassLeafNode(Node leafNodeToBypass, 
                                Node newNode) {
        Node relayNode = new Node(leafNodeToBypass.getWeight());
        Node parentOfCurrentNode = leafNodeToBypass.getParent();
 
        relayNode.setLeftChild(leafNodeToBypass);
        relayNode.setRightChild(newNode);
 
        leafNodeToBypass.setParent(relayNode);
        newNode.setParent(relayNode);
 
        if (parentOfCurrentNode == null) {
            root = relayNode;
        } else if (parentOfCurrentNode.getLeftChild() == leafNodeToBypass) {
            relayNode.setParent(parentOfCurrentNode);
            parentOfCurrentNode.setLeftChild(relayNode);
        } else {
            relayNode.setParent(parentOfCurrentNode);
            parentOfCurrentNode.setRightChild(relayNode);
        }
 
        updateMetadata(relayNode, newNode.getWeight(), 1);
    }
 
    private void insert(Node node) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }
 
        Node currentNode = root;
 
        while (currentNode.isRelayNode()) {
            if (currentNode.getLeftChild().getNumberOfLeaves() < 
                    currentNode.getRightChild().getNumberOfLeaves()) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeftChild();
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.getRightChild();
            }
        }
 
        bypassLeafNode(currentNode, node);
    }
 
    private void delete(Node leafToDelete) {
        Node relayNode = leafToDelete.getParent();
 
        if (relayNode == null) {
            root = null;
            return;
        } 
 
        Node parentOfRelayNode = relayNode.getParent();
        Node siblingLeaf = relayNode.getLeftChild() == leafToDelete ?
                                    relayNode.getRightChild() :
                                    relayNode.getLeftChild();
 
        if (parentOfRelayNode == null) {
            root = siblingLeaf;
            siblingLeaf.setParent(null);
            return;
        }
 
        if (parentOfRelayNode.getLeftChild() == relayNode) {
            parentOfRelayNode.setLeftChild(siblingLeaf);
        } else {
            parentOfRelayNode.setRightChild(siblingLeaf);
        }
 
        siblingLeaf.setParent(parentOfRelayNode);
        updateMetadata(leafToDelete.getParent(), -leafToDelete.getWeight(), -1);
    }
 
    private void updateMetadata(Node node, 
                                double weightDelta, 
                                int nodeDelta) {
        while (node != null) {
            node.setNumberOfLeaves(node.getNumberOfLeaves() + nodeDelta);
            node.setWeight(node.getWeight() + weightDelta);
            node = node.getParent();
        }
    }

    private void checkWeightNotNaNAndIsPositive(double weight) {
        if (Double.isNaN(weight)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The element weight is NaN.");
        }
 
        if (weight <= 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The element weight must be positive. Received " + weight);
        }
 
        if (Double.isInfinite(weight)) {
            // Once here, 'weight' is positive infinity.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The element weight is infinite.");
        }
    }
 
    private void checkNotEmpty(int size) {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "This probability distribution is empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.DirectedWordGraphNode.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

final class DirectedWordGraphNode 
        implements Comparable<DirectedWordGraphNode> {
    
    private final String word;
    private final BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution
            parentProbabilityDistribution = 
            new BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution();
    
    private final BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution
            childProbabilityDistribution = 
            new BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution();
    
    private final Map<DirectedWordGraphNode, Integer> childMap = 
            new HashMap<>();
    
    private final Map<DirectedWordGraphNode, Integer> parentMap = 
            new HashMap<>();
    
    public DirectedWordGraphNode(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    
    public double getChildWeight(DirectedWordGraphNode child) {
        return getParentProbabilityDistribution().getWeight(child);
    }
    
    public double getParentWeight(DirectedWordGraphNode parent) {
        return getChildProbabilityDistribution().getWeight(parent);
    }
    
    public void connectToParent(DirectedWordGraphNode parentNode) {
        if (!parentMap.containsKey(parentNode)) {
            parentMap.put(parentNode, 1);
        } else {
            parentMap.put(
                    parentNode, 
                    parentMap.get(parentNode) + 1);
        }
        
        if (!parentNode.childMap.containsKey(this)) {
            parentNode.childMap.put(this, 1);
        } else {
            parentNode.childMap.put(
                    this,
                    parentNode.childMap.get(this) + 1);
        }
    }
    
    public Set<DirectedWordGraphNode> getChildren() {
        return childMap.keySet();
    }
    
    public Set<DirectedWordGraphNode> getParents() {
        return parentMap.keySet();
    }
    
    public void computeProbabilityDistribution() {
        for (Map.Entry<DirectedWordGraphNode, Integer> entry
                : parentMap.entrySet()) {
            
            double weight = (1.0) * entry.getValue();
            
            parentProbabilityDistribution.addElement(
                    entry.getKey(), 
                    weight);
        }
        
        for (Map.Entry<DirectedWordGraphNode, Integer> entry 
                : childMap.entrySet()) {
            
            double weight = (1.0) * entry.getValue();
            
            childProbabilityDistribution.addElement(
                    entry.getKey(), 
                    weight);
        }
    }
    
    public DirectedWordGraphNode sampleParent() {
        if (parentProbabilityDistribution.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return parentProbabilityDistribution.sampleElement();
    }
    
    public BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution 
        getParentProbabilityDistribution() {
        return parentProbabilityDistribution;
    }
    
    public BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution 
        getChildProbabilityDistribution() {
        return childProbabilityDistribution;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        DirectedWordGraphNode other = (DirectedWordGraphNode) o;
        return word.equals(other.word);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return word.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DirectedWordGraphNode o) {
        return word.compareTo(o.word);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.SentenceGenerator.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator;

import com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.WordGraphBuilder.Data;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

final class SentenceGenerator {

    private static final class CommandNames {
        private static final String GENERATE_SENTENCE       = "gen";
        private static final String GET_NUMBER_OF_WORDS     = "words";
        private static final String GET_NUMBER_OF_SENTENCES = "sentences";
        private static final String LIST_ALL_WORDS          = "list";
        private static final String LIST_WORD_RANGE         = "range";
        private static final String WORD_STAT               = "stat";
        private static final String QUIT                    = "quit";
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        List<String> sentences = null;
        long totalPreprocessingDuration = 0L;
        
        try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            sentences = new SentenceProducer(args[0]).getSentences();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;
            totalPreprocessingDuration += duration;
            System.out.println("Producing sentences took " + duration + " ms.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.exit(2);
        }
        
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<List<String>> words = WordProvider.getWords(sentences);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        totalPreprocessingDuration += duration;
        
        System.out.println("Producing word data took " + duration + " ms.");
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Data data = WordGraphBuilder.buildGraph(words);
        Collections.<DirectedWordGraphNode>sort(data.graph);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        duration = endTime - startTime;
        totalPreprocessingDuration += duration;
        
        System.out.println("Building word graph took " + duration + " ms.");
        System.out.println(
                "Total preprocessing took " 
                        + totalPreprocessingDuration 
                        + " ms.");
        repl(data);
    }
    
    private static void repl(Data data) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String cmdString = scanner.nextLine();
            
            if (cmdString.startsWith(CommandNames.GENERATE_SENTENCE)) {
                processCommandGenerateSentence(cmdString, data);
            } else if (cmdString.startsWith(
                    CommandNames.GET_NUMBER_OF_SENTENCES)) {
                
                processCommandGetNumberOfSentences(
                        data.numberOfSentences);
                
            } else if (cmdString.startsWith(
                    CommandNames.GET_NUMBER_OF_WORDS)) {
                processCommandGetNumberOfWords(cmdString, data);
            } else if (cmdString.startsWith(
                    CommandNames.LIST_ALL_WORDS)) {
                processCommandListAllWords(data.graph);
            } else if (cmdString.startsWith(
                    CommandNames.LIST_WORD_RANGE)) {
                processCommandListWordRange(cmdString, data.graph);
            } else if (cmdString.startsWith(CommandNames.WORD_STAT)) {
                processShowNodeStats(cmdString, data.graphMap);
            } else if (cmdString.startsWith(CommandNames.QUIT)) {
                processCommandQuit();
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        ">>> Warning: \"" + cmdString + "\" has not parsed.");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void 
        processCommandGenerateSentence(
                String cmd,
                Data data) {
            String[] lineParts = cmd.trim().split("\\s+");
        
        if (!isWithinRange(lineParts.length, 1, 2)) {
            System.out.println(
                    ">>> Warning: Command \"" + cmd + "\" not recognized.");
            return;
        }
        
        String commandWord2 = lineParts.length > 1 ? lineParts[1] : null;
        
        int maximumSentenceLength = 
                commandWord2 != null ?
                Integer.parseInt(commandWord2) : 
                Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        
        int currentSentenceLength = 1;
        
        DirectedWordGraphNode node = data.graphMap.get(".");
        List<DirectedWordGraphNode> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(node);
        
        while (currentSentenceLength < maximumSentenceLength) {
            node = node.sampleParent();
            
            if (node == null) {
                break;
            }
            
            path.add(node);
            currentSentenceLength++;
        }
        
        Collections.<DirectedWordGraphNode>reverse(path);
        print(path);
    }
        
    private static void 
        processCommandGetNumberOfSentences(int numberOfSentences) {
        System.out.println(">>> " + numberOfSentences);
    }
        
    private static void processCommandGetNumberOfWords(String cmd, Data data) {
        String[] parts = cmd.trim().split("\\s+");
        boolean distinct = false;
        
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            distinct = (parts[1].equals("-d"));
        }
        
        System.out.println(
                ">>> " 
                        + (distinct ? 
                                data.numberOfDistinctWords :
                                data.numberOfWords));
    }
    
    private static void 
        processCommandListAllWords(List<DirectedWordGraphNode> graph) {
        graph.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    
    private static void 
        processCommandListWordRange(
                String cmd,
                List<DirectedWordGraphNode> graph) {
            
        String[] parts = cmd.trim().split("\\s+");
        
        if (!isWithinRange(parts.length, 2, 3)) {
            System.out.println("Command \"" + cmd + "\" could not be parsed.");
            return;
        }
        
        int index1;
        int index2;
        
        try {
            index1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println(parts[1] + " is not an index expression.");
            return;
        }
        
        if (!isWithinRange(index1, 0, graph.size() - 1)) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Index " 
                            + index1
                            + " is not within bounds: " 
                            + index1
                            + ", words: " 
                            + graph.size() 
                            + ".");
            return;
        }
        
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            System.out.println(graph.get(index1).getWord());
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            index2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println(parts[2] + " is not an index expression.");
            return;
        }
        
        if (!isWithinRange(index2, 0, graph.size() - 1)) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Index " 
                            + index1
                            + " is not within bounds: " 
                            + index1
                            + ", words: " 
                            + graph.size() 
                            + ".");
            return;
        }
        
        if (index1 > index2) {
            System.out.println(">>> Indices are reversed.");
            return;
        }
        
        for (int i = index1; i <= index2; i++) {
            System.out.println(graph.get(i));
        }
    }
        
    private static void 
        processShowNodeStats(
                String cmd, 
                Map<String, DirectedWordGraphNode> graphMap) {
            
        String[] parts = cmd.split("\\s+");
        String word = parts[1];
        DirectedWordGraphNode node = graphMap.get(word);
        
        if (node == null) {
            System.out.println("\"" + word + "\": no such word.");
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.println("--- Outgoing word arcs:");
        
        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution.FieldLengths fieldLengths = 
                node.getChildProbabilityDistribution().getFieldLengths();
        
        double totalWeight = 
                node.getChildProbabilityDistribution()
                    .getTotalWeight();
        
        List<DirectedWordGraphNode> children = 
                new ArrayList<>(node.getChildren());
        
        Collections.<DirectedWordGraphNode>sort(children);
        
        String fmt =
                "%-" 
                + fieldLengths.maximumWordLength
                + "s, w = %.0" 
                + fieldLengths.maximumWeightLength
                + "f, p = %f";
        
        for (DirectedWordGraphNode child : children) {
            System.out.println(
                    String.format(
                            fmt, 
                            child.getWord(), 
                            child.getChildWeight(node),
                            child.getChildWeight(node) / totalWeight));
        }
        
        System.out.println("Total of " + children.size() + " outgoing arcs.");
        children.clear();
        
        System.out.println("--- Incoming word arcs:");
        
        fieldLengths = node.getParentProbabilityDistribution()
                           .getFieldLengths();
        
        List<DirectedWordGraphNode> parents =
                new ArrayList<>(node.getParents()); 
        
        Collections.<DirectedWordGraphNode>sort(parents);
        
        fmt =
                "%-" 
                + fieldLengths.maximumWordLength
                + "s, w = %.0" 
                + fieldLengths.maximumWeightLength 
                + "f, p = %f";
        
        totalWeight = node.getParentProbabilityDistribution().getTotalWeight();
        
        for (DirectedWordGraphNode parent : parents) {
            System.out.println(
                    String.format(
                            fmt, 
                            parent.getWord(),
                            parent.getParentWeight(node),
                            parent.getParentWeight(node) / totalWeight));
        }
        
        System.out.println("Total of " + parents.size() + " incoming arcs.");
        parents.clear();
    }
        
    private static void processCommandQuit() {
        System.out.println(">>> Bye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    private static boolean isWithinRange(int value, int min, int max) {
        return !(value < min || value > max);
    }
    
    private static void print(List<DirectedWordGraphNode> path) {
        DirectedWordGraphNode node = path.get(0);
        
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = 
                new StringBuilder()
                .append(Character.toUpperCase(
                        node.getWord().charAt(0)))
                .append(node.getWord().substring(1));
        
        for (int i = 1; i < path.size(); i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ")
                         .append(path.get(i).getWord());
        }
        
        System.out.println(">>> " + stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.SentenceProducer.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

final class SentenceProducer {
    
    private static final String SPLIT_REGEX = "\\s*(\\.|\\?|;|!|—)\\s*";
    
    private final File file;
    
    public SentenceProducer(String fileName) {
        this.file = new File(fileName);
    }
    
    public List<String> getSentences() throws IOException {
        String allText = Files.readString(file.toPath());
        return splitEntireTextToSentences(allText);
    }
    
    private static List<String> splitEntireTextToSentences(String text) {
        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
        
        outerLoop:
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            
            for (int j = i; j < chars.length; j++, i++) {
                char ch = chars[j];
                
                switch (ch) {
                    case '.', '?', '!' -> {
                        stringBuilder.append(ch);
                        String newSentence = stringBuilder.toString();
                        sentences.add(newSentence);
                        continue outerLoop;
                    }
                    
                    default -> stringBuilder.append(ch);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return sentences;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.WordGraphBuilder.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

final class WordGraphBuilder {
    
    public static final class Data {
        public final List<DirectedWordGraphNode> graph;
        public final Map<String, DirectedWordGraphNode> graphMap;
        public final int numberOfSentences;
        public final int numberOfDistinctWords;
        public final int numberOfWords;
        
        private Data(List<DirectedWordGraphNode> graph,
                     Map<String, DirectedWordGraphNode> graphMap,
                     int numberOfSentences,
                     int numberOfDistinctWords,
                     int numberOfWords) {
            
            this.graph = graph;
            this.graphMap = graphMap;
            this.numberOfSentences = numberOfSentences;
            this.numberOfDistinctWords = numberOfDistinctWords;
            this.numberOfWords = numberOfWords;
        }
    }
    
    public static Data buildGraph(List<List<String>> sentenceList) {
        Map<String, DirectedWordGraphNode> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<DirectedWordGraphNode> graph = new ArrayList<>();
        
        int numberOfDistinctWords = 0;
        int numberOfWords = 0;
        
        for (List<String> sentence : sentenceList) {
            numberOfWords += sentence.size();
            
            for (String word : sentence) {
                if (!nodeMap.containsKey(word)) {
                    numberOfDistinctWords++;
                    
                    DirectedWordGraphNode directedWordGraphNode = 
                            new DirectedWordGraphNode(word);
                    
                    nodeMap.put(word, directedWordGraphNode);
                    graph.add(directedWordGraphNode);
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (List<String> sentence : sentenceList) {
            if (sentence.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size() - 1; i++) {
                String word1 = sentence.get(i);
                String word2 = sentence.get(i + 1);
                
                nodeMap.get(word2)
                       .connectToParent(
                               nodeMap.get(word1));
            }
        }
        
        for (DirectedWordGraphNode node : nodeMap.values()) {
            node.computeProbabilityDistribution();
        }
        
        return new Data(graph,
                        getGraphMap(graph),
                        sentenceList.size(),
                        numberOfDistinctWords, 
                        numberOfWords);
    }
        
    private static Map<String, DirectedWordGraphNode> 
        getGraphMap(List<DirectedWordGraphNode> graph) {
        Map<String, DirectedWordGraphNode> graphMap = 
                new HashMap<>(graph.size());
        
        for (DirectedWordGraphNode node : graph) {
            graphMap.put(node.getWord(), node);
        }
        
        return graphMap;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator.WordProvider.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.ai.sentencegenerator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

final class WordProvider {
    
    public static List<List<String>> getWords(List<String> sentences) {
        List<List<String>> returnList =
                new ArrayList<>(sentences.size());
        
        for (String sentence : sentences) {
            List<String> words = splitSentenceToWords(sentence);
            List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean addedWord = false;
            
            for (String word : words) {
                word = cleanWord(word.toLowerCase());
                
                if (word == null) {
                    continue;
                } 
                
                if (word.isBlank()) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                wordList.add(word);
                addedWord = true;
            }
            
            if (addedWord) {
                char lastChar = sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1);

                switch (lastChar) {
                    case '.' -> wordList.add(".");
                    case '?' -> wordList.add("?");
                    case '!' -> wordList.add("!");
                }

                returnList.add(wordList);
            }
        }
        
        return returnList;
    }
    
    private static String cleanWord(String word) {
        word = word.replace("“", "")
                   .replace("(", "")
                   .replace(")", "");
        
        if (word.isBlank()) {
            return null;
        }
        
        int i = 0;
        int cutOffIndex = -1;
        
        for (; i < word.length(); i++, cutOffIndex++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            
            if (ch != '‘') {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (cutOffIndex >= 0) {
            word = word.substring(cutOffIndex + 1);
        }
        
        switch (word) {
            case "’":
            case "”":
                return null;
        }
        
        if (!wordIsAlphaNumeric(word)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return word;
    }
    
    private static boolean wordIsAlphaNumeric(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    private static List<String> splitSentenceToWords(String sentence) {
        sentence = sentence.trim();
        String[] wordArray = sentence.split("\\s+|\\.|,|;|:|\"|\r|\n");
        List<String> returnArray = 
                new ArrayList<>(wordArray.length + 1);
        
        for (String word : wordArray) {
            returnArray.add(word);
        }
        
        char lastSentenceCharacter = 
                sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1);
        
        switch (lastSentenceCharacter) {
            case '.' -> returnArray.add(".");
            case '?' -> returnArray.add("?");
            case '!' -> returnArray.add("!");
        }
        
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, I would be glad to hear improvement comments.

Answer (score 1):

Code Review:

1. **SentenceProducer class**

   `private static final String SPLIT_REGEX = "\\s*(\\.|\\?|;|!|—)\\s*";`

   this regex is not used, so you can remove it.

   now the method getSentences() throws an exception which called in this term a "Checked Excpetion" which means that the compiler will force all of the usage of the method to catch the IOException or to throws it (pipeline checked exception) and this is not convenient. so instead of writing as this

   ```
   public List<String> getSentences() throws IOException {
       String allText = Files.readString(file.toPath());
       return splitEntireTextToSentences(allText);
   }
   ```

   you can write it as this:

   ```
   public List<String> getSentences() {
       try {
                   String allText = Files.readString(file.toPath());

           return splitEntireTextToSentences(allText);
       }catch (IOException exception){
           System.out.println("Exception occurred while reading the file:" + exception);
           return Collections.emptyList();
       }
   }
   ```

   about this method:

   `private static List<String> splitEntireTextToSentences(String text)`

   this shouldn't be static method because the only method that use it is getSentence() method which is not static method, so no reason to make this with static accessor.

   ## VERY IMPORTANT

   DO NOT USE LABEL, THIS IS ANTI PATTERN IN JAVA.

   so instead of creating label called outerLoop you can try refactor the code with Plain Java loops.

   what about something like this ?

   ```
   private List<String> splitEntireTextToSentences(String text) {
       char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
       List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();


       for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
           StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

           for (int j = i; j < chars.length; j++, i++) {
               char ch = chars[j];

               if ('.' == ch || '?' == ch || '!' == ch) {
                   stringBuilder.append(ch);
                   String newSentence = stringBuilder.toString();
                   sentences.add(newSentence);
                   break;
               }
               stringBuilder.append(ch);
           }
       }

       return sentences;
   }
   ```

Comment: Swallowing the exception and returning valid but incorrect results seems the wrong thing to do.  Especially if we also pollute `System.out` - why not `System.err`?  And could you explain why you are so opposed to the use of labels?  Some reasoning would help readers assess how  seriously to take that admonition.

Comment: In general console logs is depends on the flow, you can swallow the exception and do what you need according to ur business logic.
I'm avoiding using native system out / error instead I'm using Logger from slf4j

regards labeling, it's because of performance issues,, try doing jmh benchmark to check it, I will publish some,, and it's anti pattern because not all devs know about it, you can read the history of this feature.